# Insert data from custom posttype in custom posttype WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm not really familiar with this so here is my question.

I have a custom posttype for books and I got one of lessons.
I can add books, I can add lessons. Whenever I'm at the admin panel to add a new lesson, I can add books to it. Multiple lessons can connect to the same book, a book can be placed in more than one lesson.

**As I can see in my database:**

**wp_post:**

```
ID       post_title     post_content        post_type    
95       titletest      bladieblabla        lpr_lesson   
97       titletest2     a lot of content    lpr_lesson   
216      hellotest                          lpr_book
276      hellotest2                         lpr_book
```

**wp_postmeta:**

```
meta_id  post_id   meta_key       meta_value
897      216       _lpr_book_url  https://en.wikibooks.org/1
911      276       _lpr_book_url  https://en.wikibooks.org/2
985      276       _lpr_lesson    97
[..]     [..]      [..]           [..]
1001     216       _lpr_lesson    95
1002     276       _lpr_lesson    95
```

And that works fine (**remember; I've not so much experience with this**). I can connect books and lessons with each other in the admin panel. I also see it (`thumbnail`, `title` etc)

What I want; If select a lesson on the page, it will open and show me that lesson. So that means the title and content of that post. But I want it to also show the matching book(s).

I use an existing **plugin** (LearnPress, `old version 0.9.20` or something) what I used as a base.

So what I want: I want all post_id's in the table wp_postmeta which have the meta_value matching the **post_id** of the current page.

Lets say the current lesson page has the post_id of 95. Than I want to get back the post_id's 216 and 276 in the **wp_postmeta** table. So I can use those id's so I can use ID 216 first to get the URL and the thumbnail. And after that to retrieve the data from 276, etc. (And maybe the title someday if I understand it all but that it probably too hard for me now)

It's really complicated for me and I'm just stuck. And it's really, really bugging me (it's 04:45 right now lol)
I can retrieve the ID of the lesson if I do `$echo $lesson_id`;
But I just have no clue how to get the matching data to show the books.

The part of the code that works to get the data of the lesson is here http://pastebin.com/PERv6g5L

Of course I want a solution to get this done, but if possible I also want a (small) explanation how and why so I learn to understand how it all works.

**I know I (probably?) should use something like:**

```
$books = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT          pm.meta_value
    FROM            $wpdb->posts        AS p
    INNER JOIN      $wpdb->postmeta     AS pm  ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE           mp.meta_key = _lpr_lesson
    OR              mp.meta_key = _lpr_book_url             
    "
    )
);
```

And than some code to display it on the screen.
But, something else. I'm just really confused.

I'll send cookies and chocolate to the one who can help me out.

***EDIT EDIT EDIT:***

The answer of milan kyada didn't work out for me.

I figured out that I can retrieve the lesson id by $lesson_id. With this lesson id I can search meta_value for corresponding books. This also means I only need to use the table **wp_postmeta**.

So I search meta_value for $lesson_id and than I want corresponding post_id (of books: 216 for example). Then I try to use those post_id(s) to get the meta_value by filtering on that post_id with the meta_key _lpr_book_url or _thumbnail_id. So I get 2 results: The URL and the thumbnail id.

So what i tried:

```
$books = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT      meta_value
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE       (meta_key = '_lpr_book_url'  OR  meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    AND         post_id = (
        SELECT      post_id
        FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE       meta_value = $lesson_id
        GROUP BY    meta_value
    )
"
);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => https://www.brinkman-uitgeverij.nl/lesmateriaal/backend-programmeren ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => 272 ) )
```

This doen't work. It returns only the first book it finds, not the others. If I use GROUP BY post_id I don't get any result at all.

If I use this:

```
$books_id = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT      pm.post_id
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta  AS pm
    WHERE       pm.meta_value = $lesson_id
    "
);

print_r($books_id);
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 216 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [post_id] => 276 ) )
```

I get 1 or more book id's corresponding the lesson. So I want the rest:

```
$books = $wpdb->get_results (
    "
    SELECT      meta_value
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE       post_id = 216
    AND         (meta_key = '_lpr_book_url'  OR  meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    "
);
```

returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => https://en.wikibooks.org/1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [meta_value] => 272 ) )
```

But as you can see. I used hardcoded 216. If I use $book_id instead, It doesn't work.

How can I fix this? Or merge the two tables as one?

Comment: `$lesson_id` is your current post id? And you want all that posts which has `_lpr_lesson=$lesson_id` ? Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are. So that I get 216 and 276 for example. So I can get the post_title and thumbnail in wp_post table.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
$books = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT      meta_value
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE       (meta_key = '_lpr_book_url'  OR  meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    AND         post_id IN (
            SELECT      post_id
            FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE       meta_value = $lesson_id
    )
    ORDER BY    post_id, meta_key
    "
);
```

I should have used IN instead of =.